# TFS 2015 Build files and Publish websites

Tags: asp.net, wpf, tfs, tfsbuild

I recently started working with TFS 2015 (Update 4). And I'm trying to configure and build to do the folowing:

- Restore nuget packets
- Build whole solution
- Publish (move to specific uri)

My solution has the folowing structure:

- Solution

  - DALs (EF6 code first model)
  - WPF App 1
  - ASP.NET Website 1
  - WPF App 2
  - ASP.NET Website 2

Note: Both Websites have publish profiles named "Publish", and both are same except the `publishUrl` inside of them.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>..\Deploy\AppServerHost</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

What have I tried on TFS...
[image: The build]
And the publish:
[image: publishing the artifact]

What I'm trying to acomplish, is that when I start the build, it should build the whole solution, copy the release of `WPF` regulary, and most important, not just build the websites, it should also publish them. Because now I only get their bins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build the whole solution, you need to make sure you have mapped all your projects/the whole solution folder in Repository tab, and specify the solution or use `**\*.sln` (you have already done this according to your screenshot) in `Visual Studio Build` task:

[image]

You only get bins because you only specify `**\bin`in Contents of `Copy and Publish Build Artifacts` task. Since you are using TFS 2015.4, we recommend that you do not use `Copy and Publish Build Artifacts` task, it's deprecated. Instead, you should use the [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files) and [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts) tasks.

In `Copy Files` task, specify match pattern filters (one on each line) that you want to apply to the list of files to be copied.

In `Publish Build Artifacts` task, specify the path to the folder or file you want to publish. You could refer to the links for more details.

Comment: Could you give me an example of `Copy Files`. As I understand, I should make so many `Copy Files` as much I have projects?
And where to set the `Target Folder` to then?
I'm trying to publish my files also to a file system, so if you have any live example how to do it, I would appreciate.

Comment: @FiN You could check the examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files#examples. Target folder is the folder where the files will be copied. In most cases you specify this folder using a variable. For example, specify `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` if you intend to publish the files as build artifacts.

Comment: @FiN Are you able to make `Copy Files` task working?

Comment: Yes It works perfectly, just could you tell me how to write the `Content` to allow `.config` files and `bin` folder.